# How can I remove white squares on Google Chrome home page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I never use the suggested sites so I want to be able to remove the white boxes on the Google Chrome home page. How can I do this? (Photo below with crude drawing)

[image]

Comment: What's the address in your address bar? Those squares are not part of the google design (if you're not logged in). If they only appear after you login it's likely there is an option to disable them somewhere in the settings. If they're part of an extension (suggested by your tags) ... remove that extension?

Comment: @Seth this is the "quick launch" home page in Chrome, not the actual Google page. It is the default home page in chrome by the looks of it.

Comment: As far as I can tell what you're seeing is actually a google hosted site (https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab). If Chrome doesn't have an inbuilt option to ignore part of the code of that site you probably won't be able to change it. You might be able to use a Extension to redirect a new tab to google directly or change that in some other way.

Comment: Max - A simple solution may be to quickly press either `Alt`+`Home` or press the Chrome [Home Page](https://i.imgur.com/DRRhZIR.png) button and the Google search engine will not display those frequently used site squares. It seems if you load `https://www.google.com/` as your home page and set the `Show Home Page` button that those are two quick workarounds potentially. Not sure if that'd suffice for your needs but if you're interested in that idea, please let me know.

Comment: To further clarify though, if you have your home page set to `https://www.google.com/` and when you open Chome and Google search engine is your home page that it goes to initially when lauched or you open a new tab, those squares show like that. However, when you go to your home page after that by pressing the hot keys or the Home page button, the squares no longer show.... Weird but that seems to be the way it works from how I tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome does not give users the option to alter the new tab page, but this [Replace New Tab Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/replace-new-tab-page/cnkhddihkmmiiclaipbaaelfojkmlkja) extension will do the trick. I use it myself.

Once installed go to More Tools > Extensions, then click [options] under the Replace New Tab Page info, then type in the URL of the page you want to display. Then click [Save].

Answer (score 0):

You can also use New Tab Redirect (for Google Chrome), which is an extension free from the Chrome Web Store:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna?hl=en

You can enable, disable or delete this plug-in any time you want.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I have an Nvidia graphics card. Chrome is of course a memory hog. So I went into the Nvidia control panel, then into where you can pick individual programs and set the Nvidia setting per program. I set max rendered frames from 2 aka the default setting to 4 frames rendered. the problem went away. It was really bad on Facebook but no longer exists there.

I also set the card to use the processors on the card only to process all graphics. Auto is the default value. I was not expecting it to work but it did.

[image]